# How did Einstein get back from the future if he can't drive?

Tags: back-to-the-future

In the first *Back to the Future*, Einstein, the dog, gets sent forward in time by 1 minute. If you have to reach 88 miles per hour, how did he get back? He can't drive a car, he's a dog.

Comment: Einstein? In Back to the Future?

Comment: @Edlothiad - https://sniffandbarkens.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/einsteins2.jpg

Comment: TIL there’s a dog in Back to the Future. I swear I’ve seen each film at least twice...

Comment: How did Laika, the first dog to be sent to space get there? She can't fly the damn space shuttle.

Comment: @Edlothiad, Doc has the same breed of dog (presumably played by the same dog) in the 1955 timeline, but he's called Copernicus.

Answer (score 23):

***The Doc is very clearly seen driving the car with a remote control.***

The car is sent one minute into the future. Doc and Marty chat for a minute, and then the car reappears. From the perspective of Einstein, no time at all has passed between the Delorean disappearing and reappearing (in fact, I think Doc says as much in the film).

So it seems like even after all these years, people don’t get this so here is a timeline of what happens;

[image]

Just before point A, Doc, Marty and Einstein are all together. Doc controls the car with Einstein in and accelerates it to 88mph. At point A, the car disappears 1 minute into the future. At that point in time, *Einstein does not exist*. One minute passes, and at point B, the car from one minute ago appears. Einstein then continues to exist in the timeline. To Einstein, the time between points A and B did not happen. He went instantaneously from A to B. There was no “going back”. He continues on as if nothing happens, although physically he is one minute younger than he should be, having not existed between points A and B.

Comment: Don't think this answers the question. How did he get BACK. Doc used remote to get him a minute ahead. But the Delorean has to reach 88mph to get back. Otherwise Einstein will always be 1 minute ahead. It can't "catch up" as Doc described in the movie. I think this is a plot hole.

Comment: @KenPowers Back where? Car is sent one minute into the future by Doc, with remote control. Doc and Marty wait one minute, car appears. It’s really very simple.

Comment: @KenPowers I added some more info that will hopefully explain it more clearly.

Comment: Yes, Einstein will always be 1 minute ahead.

Answer (score 0):

He didn't drive back he was sent 1 minute into the future by Doc, he technically didn't stop. Just as Marty didn't stop at any point between 1955 and 1985 when returning. It's the same principle.

Answer (score -1):

If Einstein had returned to the start, there would be two of him: the Einstein which was anout to leave and the one who just returned. But he never returned, he just shifted 60 seconds to the future then just carried on. Simple.

Answer (score -2):

Einstein would be one minute ahead FOREVER, doc and marty would never see him again.  Send him instantly one minute into the future and time for him does not stop there, you would never 'catch up'

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm not sure this makes sense.  Can't they just wait a minute for him to show up?  It's not like when Doc goes back to 1885 the car is forever 70 years behind Marty; in 1955 Marty goes and gets the car.

Comment: That's incorrect. The Doc sent Einstein forward in time one minute. He and Marty then travel forward one minute (the slow way) where they find him exiting the wormhole.